# unknown shorthand flag: 'e' in -e Docker login

Tags: ubuntu, docker, openshift

Для подключения к registry Openshift в веб-морде предлагается ввести:

```
$ docker login -p MRоу12у1гшр12уги21 -e unused -u unused imya.repostirya.moy.domen.ru
```

При этом Docker не знает ключ **-e**

```
unknown shorthand flag: 'e' in -e
See 'docker login --help'
```

И действительно в справке ничего подобного нет.

```
$ docker login --help

Usage:  docker login [OPTIONS] [SERVER]

Log in to a Docker registry

Options:
  -p, --password string   Password
      --password-stdin    Take the password from stdin
  -u, --username string   Username
```

Если убрать этот параметр, авторизоваться удается, однако не понятно что это за параметр, на что он влияет и почему он указан в команде подключения к registry Openshift.

Может кто знает?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос закрыт!

Оказалось это параметр отвечает за email и он не поддерживается в более новых версиях Docker